# finding duplicate values with join

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

**ITEMS**

```
ITEM_ID NAME_ID ITEM_NAME
1001    2001    Office chair
1002    2002    Writing Desk
1003    2003    Filing cabinet
1004    2004    Bookshelf bookcase
1005    2005    Table lamp
1006    2001    Office chair
1007    2002    Writing Desk
1008    2003    Filing cabinet
1009    2004    Bookshelf bookcase
1010    2005    Table lamp
1011    2001    Office chair
1012    2002    Writing Desk
1013    2003    Filing cabinet
1014    2004    Bookshelf bookcase
1015    2005    Table lamp
1016    2016    Triangle window
1017    2017    Screen
1018    2018    Cradle
1019    2017    Screen
1020    2018    Cradle
1021    2017    Screen
1022    2018    Cradle
1023    2023    Futon
1024    2024    Single bed
1025    2025    Bunk beds
1026    2026    Sofa bed
1027    2027    Camp bed  cot    sleeping bag
1028    2028    Airbed  air mattress
1029    2029    Hammock
1030    2030    Loveseat
1031    2031    Sleeper sofa
1032    2032    Settee
1032    2032    Settee
1033    2001    Office chair
1034    2002    Writing Desk
1035    2003    Filing cabinet
1036    2004    Bookshelf/bookcase
1037    2005    Table lamp
1038    2001    Office chair
1039    2002    Writing Desk
1040    2003    Filing cabinet
1041    2004    Bookshelf/bookcase
1042    2005    Table lamp
1043    2017    Screen
1044    2018    Cradle
1045    2017    Screen
1046    2018    Cradle
1047    2017    Screen
1048    2018    Cradle
1049    2017    Screen
1050    2018    Cradle
```

**ITEMS_DETAILS:**

```
CITY    ITEM_ID SHOP_ID
NEW YORK    1001    4001
NEW YORK    1002    4002
NEW YORK    1003    4003
NEW YORK    1004    4004
NEW YORK    1005    4005
DALLAS  1006    4006
DALLAS  1007    4007
DALLAS  1008    4008
DALLAS  1009    4001
DALLAS  1010    4002
DALLAS  1011    4003
DALLAS  1012    4004
WASHINGTON  1013    4005
WASHINGTON  1014    4006
WASHINGTON  1015    4007
WASHINGTON  1016    4008
WASHINGTON  1017    4009
WASHINGTON  1018    4010
WASHINGTON  1019    4011
SANFRANSISCO    1020    4012
SANFRANSISCO    1021    4013
CHICAGO 1022    4014
CHICAGO 1023    4015
CHICAGO 1024    4016
CHICAGO 1025    4017
BOSTON  1026    4018
BOSTON  1027    4019
BOSTON  1028    4020
BOSTON  1029    4021
BOSTON  1030    4022
SANFRANSISCO    1031    4023
SANFRANSISCO    1032    4024
SANFRANSISCO    1032    4025
SANFRANSISCO    1033    4026
Las Vegas   1034    4027
Austin  1035    4028
Houston 1036    4029
Los Angeles 1037    4030
Seattle 1038    4031
Atlanta 1039    4032
McKinney    1040    4033
Vancouver   1041    4034
Las Vegas   1042    4035
Austin  1043    4036
Houston 1044    4037
Los Angeles 1045    4038
Seattle 1046    4034
Atlanta 1047    4035
McKinney    1048    4036
Vancouver   1049    4037
Las Vegas   1050    4043
Austin  1051    4044
Houston 1052    4045
Los Angeles 1053    4046
Seattle 1054    4047
Atlanta 1055    4048
McKinney    1056    4049
Vancouver   1057    4050
Las Vegas   1058    4051
Austin  1059    4052
Houston 1060    4053
```

Hi All,
I am trying to find the duplicates values of the columns after the result of the join ITEMS & ITEM_DETAILS.
I know the sql for duplicate values of column on a single table. A bit confused with join.

**Logic**: If ITEM_NAME is the same but SHOP_ID is different, it should show as duplicate. If SHOP_ID is the same, it should show as unique

Please help me.

I tried as below:

```
select * from (
select  a.NAME_ID from ITEMS a inner join ITEMS_DETAILS b on b.ITEM_ID = a.ITEM_ID) x
inner join ITEMS y on y.NAME_ID=x.NAME_ID
inner join ITEMS_DETAILS z on z.ITEM_ID=y.ITEM_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in grouping and counting dups then try the query below:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) As DupCount,
    y.ITEM_ID
FROM
    ITEMS y 
    INNER JOIN ITEMS_DETAILS z ON z.ITEM_ID=y.ITEM_ID
GROUP BY
    y.ITEM_ID
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This will give you only duplicated ITEM_IDs. I want to derive a column by using the condition: If ITEM_NAME is the same but SHOP_ID is different, it should show as duplicate. If SHOP_ID is the same, it should show as unique

Comment: Do you mean ITEM_NAME or ITEM_ID is different?

Comment: Yes. In ITEMS_DETAILS same ITEM_NAME has different ITEM_ID.ITEM_IDs are no duplicates in ITEMS & ITEMS_DETAILS tables. Only ITEM_NAME,SHOPI_IDs are duplicates. Based on  ITEM_NAME,SHOPI_IDs need to define a flag column